# When loading static resources in a WAS environment, "SessionRepositoryFilter" is invoked

Tags: java

I am currently using `jdbcSpringSession`.
When requesting static resources required by WAS
`SessionRepositoryFilter`, `doFilterInterval`
will be called.
Can't call `SessionRepositoryFilter` if I request static resources?

Spring Security tried the following.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/font/**", "/webjars/**","/favicon.ico","/dispatch/**","/summernote/**","/down/**", "/assets/**");
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.